# How to return children objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, single-table-inheritance

I have -- what I think -- is a simple question.  Here's my code:

```
class Fruit < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class Apple < Fruit
end

class Kiwi < Fruit
end
```

Assume that I have all the STI setup correctly, and there are multiple types of Apple and Kiwi records in the table.  From here...

```
fruits = Fruit.find(:all)
```

...how do I return an array of just Apples from the fruits array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same way you would do it if they were just normal objects:

```
fruits.select {|fruit| fruit.is_a?(Apple) }
```

STI uses the `type` field to keep track of the submodel, so you could also do

```
fruits.select {|fruit| fruit.type == "Apple" }
```

If you want to get only the apples from the database, just do

```
Apple.find(:all)
```